# TypeArgumentException in silverlight lambda expression

Tags: silverlight, dynamic, expression-trees

I've defined the following method

```
public static Expression<Func<T,dynamic>> CreateExpression(string propName)
{
ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));

MemberExpression aggregator = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter,propName);

return Expression.Lambda<Func<T,dynamic>>(aggregator,param);
}
```

The code compiles OK but in the runtime the last line
throws argumentexception stating 'Expression of Type 'System.Int32' cannot be used for return type 'System.Object'

Am i missing something?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use [Expression.Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292051.aspx). That will add the boxing conversion you require to turn the Int32 basic type (or any basic type you reference) into an object.

Comment: In such case the following EntityQuery fails.
Isn't the dynamic keyword supposed to mean I can put anything into the variable and it'll be resolved in runtime?

Comment: "the *following* EntityQuery fails"... Huh?  Did you put brackets in your comment or am I going mad[der]? Can you please provide an example of your usage as well so we can post a specific answer.